# Rails 3. How to default sort by a virtual attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activeadmin

I have shipments has one invoice; and invoice belongs to shipment.
Shipment has the reference_number attribute.

I'm using activeadmin and I list the shipments sorted by the file_number in the index page, like this...

```
shipment.rb
default_scope :order => :file_number
```

I want to list the invoices in the index page sorted by the reference number, the problem is that reference number is a virtual attribute based on shipments.

```
invoice.rb
def reference_number
  if self.shipment.nil?
    a = "no ref"
  else
    self.shipment.file_number
  end
end
```

Comment: You could sort in the application.

Comment: if I do this `link_to invoice.reference_number, admin_invoice_path(invoice)` I get a no such column: invoice.reference_number error

Comment: did you restart your server after adding this meod? This matters when your app already is in production in development its wheater and the problem is on another place...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
default_scope includes(:shipment).order("shipments.file_number")
```

In this case, obviously all the nils will be ordered together so you can add logic for the "no ref" string in the view when shipment.blank? or just stick with reference_number method in the view.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest to you a weird method, first refactory

```
invoice.rb
def reference_number
  self.shipment.nil? ? "no ref" : self.shipment.file_number
end

def <=> (obj2)
  self.reference_number <=> obj2.reference_number
end
def < (obj2)
  self.reference_number < obj2.reference_number
end
def > (obj2)
  self.reference_number > obj2.reference_number
end
def == (obj2)
  self.reference_number = obj2.reference_number
end
```

that's it!, when you fill view, you must include (sort):

```
@invoices= Invoice.all.sort
```